# Classification in the presence of dependent events

Tags: classification, conditional-probability, prior, joint-distribution, independence

In a classification problem, I have a number of $n$ disjoint and exhaustive (and also likely) events $C_i$ defined as a joint event by

$$
C_i = H_{i1} \cap H_{i2} \cap ... \cap H_{im},
$$

where $H_{ij}$ are not necessarily independent events, they have prior/marginal probabilities pdfs $f_{H_{ij}}(r_{j})$ and may be modeled as either $H_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_{ij},\,\sigma^{2}_{ij})\,$ or  $H_{ij} \sim {U}(h_{ijl},\,h_{ijh})\,$.

Given an outcome $R = \{H_1=r_1\} \cap \{H_2=r_2\}\, \cap  ... \cap \,\{H_m=r_m\}$, it is possible to evaluate the $m$ conditionals $Pr(H_{ij}|R)$  for each class $i$ since the distribution of each event $H_{j}$ is a mixture of the events $H_{ij}$ over the classes $i$.

It is then necessary to evaluate 
$$
Pr(C_i|R) = Pr(H_{i1} \cap H_{i2} \cap ... \cap H_{im} | R ) \,,
$$

so I can use a MAP estimator (for example) but the events $H_{i1}, H_{i2},..., H_{im}$ are not necessarily independent (within a same class $i$) and I do not have either the conditional probabilities $Pr(H_{ij}|H_{il})$ or the joint $Pr(H_{ij}\,\cap\,H_{il})$ ones. Hence, I can't go further with the classification.

I know that it is possible to apply a naive classifier assuming that the given events are independent ones to evaluate $Pr(C_i|R)$ by

$$
Pr(C_i|R) = \prod_{j=1}^{m}Pr(H_{ij} | R)\,,
$$

and then verify if its performance is satisfactory for my application, but I have some questions I would like to post:

1 - If I had a discrete case, it would be possible to evaluate the conditional probabilities  $Pr(H_{ij}|H_{il})$ by means of 'simple' tables.  In this case, could I use these probabilities to evaluate $Pr(C_i|R)$ instead of the ones that came from the process from where the random variables where extracted?
As an example, if we had the following discrete case

```
   H1  H2  H3 
C1 1   2   1 
C2 3   2   0 
C3 1   0   3 
C4 2   0   0
```

it would not be difficult to evaluate all the conditional and joint probabilities between the variables $H_i$. Could I use them as the conditional and joint probabilities necessary to evaluate $Pr(C_i|R)$?

2 - If the answer is yes to the question (1), how could I evaluate the conditional and joint probabilities for the case where the values of $H_i$ are continuous random variables?

3 - Given that the probabilities $Pr( H_{ij} | R)$ are disponible, i.e. the probabibities of the 'states'  $H_{ij}$ given the outcome $R$, could I use a (Hidden) Markov Chain to model the problem even if it is not possible to assure that $Pr( H_{i1}\,\cap\,H_{i2}\,\cap\,...H_{im})$ is given by $Pr(H_{i1})Pr(H_{i2}|H_{i1})Pr(H_{i3}|H_{i2})..Pr(H_{im}|H_{i(m-1)})$?

4 - What other techniques I could use for my case?